# Finding solutions of a matrix with parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Given the system of equations:

> $ x_1 + βx_2 + βx_3 + βx_4 = α $
>
> $x_1 + (1 + β) x_2 + (α + β) x_3 + 2βx_4 = α + β$
>
> $2x_1 + 2βx_2 + (α + 2β) x_3 + (α + 2β) x_4 = 3α$
>
> $3x_1 + 3βx_2 + 3βx_3 + (α + 2β) x_4 = 4α + 2$

I need to find the values of $\alpha,\:\beta\:\in\mathbb{R}$ such as that the system has:

1. a unique solution
2. infinite solutions
3. no solutions

Now obviously the first thing that comes to mind is using Gaussian elimination until a row echelon form is reached, but that seems exceptionally cumbersome with the parameters α and β. Is there a neater way to solve this that I'm missing?

Comment: For #2: Just looking at the first and fourth equations: if you multiply eq.1 by 3 and compare to eq.4 then the LHS's are equal for $\alpha = \beta$. And the RHS's are equal for $\alpha = \beta = -2$. So now both equations are the same so you have 3 equations in 4 unknowns so there are infinite solutions. (assuming Eq.2 and Eq.3 are well behaved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Gaussian-elimination,

$\begin{cases}x_1 + \beta x_2 + βx_3 + βx_4 = α \\ x_1 + (1 + β) x_2 + (α + β) x_3 + 2βx_4 = α + β\color{red}{(II-I)}\\2x_1 + 2βx_2 + (α + 2β) x_3 + (α + 2β) x_4 = 3α\color{red}{(III-2\times I)}\\3x_1 + 3βx_2 + 3βx_3 + (α + 2β) x_4 = 4α + 2\color{red}{(IV-3\times I)}\end{cases}$
$$\iff$$

$\begin{cases}x_1 + \beta x_2 + βx_3 + βx_4 = α \\  x_2 + α x_3 + βx_4 = β\\ α x_3 + α x_4 = 3α\\(α -β) x_4 = α + 2\end{cases}$

*First case*: $\alpha=0$. Then this system is equivalent to $$\begin{cases}x_1 + \beta x_2 + βx_3 + βx_4 = 0 \\  x_2  + βx_4 = β\\-β x_4 =  2\end{cases}$$
If $\beta=0$ then the system has no solution.

If $\beta\neq0$ then $$\begin{cases}x_1=2+2\beta-\beta^2-\beta x_3\\  x_2  = -2+β\\x_4 = -\frac{2}{\beta} \end{cases}$$

This system has infinite solutions.

*Second case*: $\alpha \neq 0.$

If $\beta=\alpha\neq-2$, there is no solution.

If $\beta=\alpha=-2$ then $\begin{cases}x_1-2 x_2 -2x_3 -2x_4 = -2\\  x_2 -2 x_3 -2x_4 = -2\\ x_3 +  x_4 = 3\end{cases}$

This system has infinite solutions.

If $\beta\neq \alpha$, the system has a unique solution.